# Store data from useQuery with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I'm using React hooks both to fetch GraphQL data with `react-apollo` and to store local state:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USER_QUERY)
```

However, I'm wondering how to store `data` to `userData`. Is this how it's supposed to work:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUserData(data)
}, [Object.entries(data).length])
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like what you have probably works. There is also a `onCompleted` option available in the `options` parameter. it takes a callback of type:

```
(data: TData | {}) => void
```

so this is another way of doing it:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USER_QUERY, {onCompleted: setUserData})
```

Comment: I think "onCompleted" should be "onSuccess".

Comment: @d0utone at least in version 3.5.10, it is `onCompleted`

Comment: Why is data is not being used in onCompleted? How does it know what to set use state to?

Answer (score 10):

What are you trying to do with the returned data that you are unable to accomplish by simply using it as destructured from the query hook?  In most use cases it can be used immediately, as it will update itself when refetched.

If it is necessary (and it could be), as the other answer says, the `useEffect` hook you posted should work, but I would replace the dependency with simply `data`, to prevent an edge case where the response has an equal length consisting of different data and does not update:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUserData(data)
}, [data])
```

Comment: Using `useEffect` in this way is not recommended because it will run only after the component is mounted resulting in a delay between `loading` === true and `setUserData` being populated.

More information in the react docs
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this would work - you will need to create the initial state with useState, could be empty array and then onComplete in the useQuery would setTranscationsData... it is triggered `every render when state or props change`. Could of course add an inital state inside useState which insn't an empty array.

```js
const [transactionsData, setTransactionsData] = React.useState([]);

const { error, data } = useQuery(GET_TRANSACTIONS, {
  onCompleted: () => {
    setTransactionsData(data.transactions);
  },
});
```

another example

```
  const [getLegalStatement] = useLazyQuery(GET_LEGAL_STATEMENT, {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setTempLegalStatement(data.getLegalStatement);
    },
    onError: () => {
      setTempLegalStatement({
        consentedLegalStatementHash: '',
        consentedSuppliersHash: '',
        statement: '',
        suppliersModal: '',
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        setRefetchNeeded(true);
      }, 10000);
    },
  });
```

Comment: This will cause a warning: 'data' was used before it was defined.

Comment: We use this pattern pretty widely, have you tested your error? I think I wrote it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure why I am seeing a warning. I copied your code exactly.

Comment: Have updated with another example, it definitely works, may be a setup thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onSuccess`

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})
const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery('QueryKey', QueryFunction, { onSuccess: setUserData })
```

This `onSuccess` callback function will fire `setUserData(data)` for you automatically any time the query successfully fetches new data.

Comment: This will cause a warning: `'data' was used before it was defined`. There is no obvious way to get around that, so another solution would probably be better.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate above, you can't use onSuccess/onSettled because those will not rerun if the data is cached, so if you leave the component and come back before the query expires your data won't get set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33612669)